# Why is it called the category of representations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, terminology, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a (Hopf) algebra. Let $C_A$ be a category whose objects are $A$-modules and whose morphisms are $A$-linear maps.

This category is called "the category of representations".

My question is: why is it called the category of representations? Is there any relation to other area of mathematics? What does it represent? Is it called representations only for "Hopf" algebras?

Answer (score 3):

In representation theory people often use the word representation as a synonym for module, and for good reason.  A representation of a Lie algebra is the same thing as a module for its universal enveloping algebra, a representation of a quiver is the same as a module over its path algebra, etc.

One important example is that a representation of a finite group is the same thing as a module over its group algebra, which is naturally a (cocommutative) Hopf algebra. Perhaps that can motivate the terminology.

Answer (score 3):

For a given group $G$ and field $F$, the category of group representations of $G$ (in the sense of group homomorphisms from $G$ into $GL(n,F)$) is equivalent to the category of finite dimensional modules over the group ring $F[G]$.

Similarly, the category of $F$-algebra representations of an algebra $A$ (in the sense of ring homomorphisms from $A$ into $M_n(F)$) is equivalent to the category of finite dimensional $A$ modules.

These are the two main connections between "representations" in the sense of "modeling an object as a set of matrices" and related categories of modules.